# reshape dataset based on multiple colums

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, tidyr

I reshaped data before, but the cells could always be identified by two variables. This isn't possible with my current data. An extract of my data looks like this. The full dataset covers more countries and years.

| Country | Fear of Crime | TOTAL | 2007 | 2009 | 2010 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Argentina | All or almost the time | 37 | 37 | 33 | 27 |
| Argentina | Sometimes | 34 | 42 | 35 | 40 |
| Argentina | Occasionally | 18 | 14 | 23 | 23 |
| Argentina | Never | 11 | 6 | 8 | 10 |
| Argentina | Don´t know/No answer | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Bolivia | All or almost the time | 38 | 35 | 36 | 34 |
| Bolivia | Sometimes | 36 | 40 | 41 | 40 |
| Bolivia | occasionally | 17 | 17 | 18 | 18 |
| Bolivia | Never | 8 | 6 | 4 | 6 |
| Bolivia | Don´t know/No answer | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I would need the data in this format:

| Year | Country | All or almost the time | Sometimes | occasionally | Never | Don´t know/No answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Does anyone have a solution? Thank you a lot!

Comment: So you want to reshape from long to wide. Please add a small reproducible example, i. e. code that runs in a R session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the following solution. I added `TOTAL` values to `Year` variable and also made a s slight change to `Fear_of_Crime` so that all values are title_case:

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(TOTAL:X2010, names_to = "Year", names_prefix = "X?") %>%
  mutate(Fear_of_Crime = str_to_title(Fear_of_Crime)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Fear_of_Crime, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 8 x 7
  Country   Year  All_or_almost_the_time Sometimes Occasionally Never `Don´T_know/No_answer`
  <chr>     <chr>                  <int>     <int>        <int> <int>                  <int>
1 Argentina TOTAL                     37        34           18    11                      0
2 Argentina 2007                      37        42           14     6                      1
3 Argentina 2009                      33        35           23     8                      1
4 Argentina 2010                      27        40           23    10                      0
5 Bolivia   TOTAL                     38        36           17     8                      1
6 Bolivia   2007                      35        40           17     6                      1
7 Bolivia   2009                      36        41           18     4                      0
8 Bolivia   2010                      34        40           18     6                      1
```

Comment: I had some small errors when i applied it to my actual data. I had to rename "Fear of Crime" to Fear_of_Crime and add an X to very Year, but then it worked. Thank you!

Comment: The `names_prefix` argument just drops any prefix that previous column names had when we store them in a new variable. Here I used `?` for zero or one in case a name like `TOTAL` didn't have prefix `X` it would remain as is. I also noticed that `Occasionally` is in lower case in another observation so the output column separated the two so I decided to transform all to title_case. I also put underscore for your names separated by space or `\\s` but you can also use back ticks ` `` `.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
    pivot_longer(
        cols = -c(Country, `Fear of Crime`),
        names_to = "Year"
    ) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        id_cols = c(Year, Country),
        names_from = `Fear of Crime`,
        values_from = value
    )

# A tibble: 6 x 7
#  Year  Country     All Sometimes Occasionally Never `Don't know`
#  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 2007  Argentina  52.0      29.7         52.1  34.2         59.9
#2 2009  Argentina  52.8      38.1         42.0  73.5         42.9
#3 2010  Argentina  56.2      64.6         31.0  71.6         32.1
#4 2007  Bolivia    36.8      37.4         31.4  45.0         56.3
#5 2009  Bolivia    53.2      52.8         62.8  56.1         59.9
#6 2010  Bolivia    42.4      45.1         67.4  55.0         58.1
```

Data:

```
dat <- tibble(
    Country = rep(c("Argentina", "Bolivia"), each = 5),
    `Fear of Crime` = rep(c("All", "Sometimes", "Occasionally", "Never", "Don't know"), 2),
    `2007` = rnorm(10, 50, 10),
    `2009` = rnorm(10, 50, 10),
    `2010` = rnorm(10, 50, 10)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)

dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.vars = c('Country', 'Fear of Crime')), 
      Country + variable ~ `Fear of Crime` , value.var = 'value')

#     Country variable      All Don't know    Never Occasionally Sometimes
#1: Argentina     2007 61.35123   51.64059 52.90937     56.06212  51.27404
#2: Argentina     2009 49.97756   48.41825 67.63133     35.55390  46.89938
#3: Argentina     2010 54.35360   57.17569 43.49386     54.01240  59.79714
#4: Argentina    Total 77.11749   66.08187 57.24466     82.39351  89.21991
#5:   Bolivia     2007 53.28061   49.66029 39.45862     54.87632  36.10037
#6:   Bolivia     2009 32.22393   44.43537 56.89622     58.62973  40.09476
#7:   Bolivia     2010 43.81035   43.07929 39.85770     57.56582  49.35075
#8:   Bolivia    Total 97.55278   57.06825 72.95792     87.52021  59.40992
```